# import tf2/StaticTransformPublisher in Python

Tags: ros, tf2-ros, tf2, rospy, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm following this tutorial[1] and having trouble with importing.

[1] http://wiki.ros.org/tf2/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf2%20static%20broadcaster%20(Python)

```
>>> import tf2_ros
>>> tf2_ros.StaticTransformPublisher()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'StaticTransformPublisher'
```

Using up-to-date Indigo with Trusty.

```
$ dpkg -s ros-indigo-tf2-ros | grep Version
Version: 0.5.13-0trusty-20161025-211630-0700
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/251554/import-tf2/statictransformpublisher-in-python/) by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10932 on 2017-01-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Michael Johnson](https://answers.ros.org/users/26650/michael-johnson/) on 2017-01-09**:
What is it you are trying to do?
`static_transform_publisher` is a command line tool which can be used like this:

```
static_transform_publisher x y z yaw pitch roll frame_id child_frame_id period_in_ms
```

http://wiki.ros.org/tf#static_transform_publisher

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2017-01-09**:
I appreciate the link, but I hate that command line interface and am trying to rewrite it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The real problem is that the debian has not been updated. https://github.com/ros/geometry2/issues/199

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2017-01-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like `StaticTransformPublisher` was renamed to  `StaticTransformBroadcaster`. The API looks the same though so you should just be able to directly replace it.

[github link](https://github.com/ros/geometry2/blob/439e2350ca9b2f0581a3631f0929acc2021db73e/tf2_ros/src/tf2_ros/static_transform_broadcaster.py)

---

Originally posted by [Michael Johnson](https://answers.ros.org/users/26650/michael-johnson/) with karma: 154 on 2017-01-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2